# How to Make a Discord Bot Join a Voice Channel and Play an Audio File When a Member Joins the Channel Using Discord.py Cogs

Tags: python-3.x, audio, discord.py

### My Current Project

I am currently trying to make a cog for a Discord bot in Python 3 that, when running, plays a specific audio file when someone joins a specific Discord voice channel.

### My Problem

I already have the code for my project(credit: [Tabulate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11591238/tabulate)), but I don't know how to

1. Convert it to a cog, and
2. Make it work for a *specific* voice channel, and not every one in the Discord
   server.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep

rpgmusicpath = r"C:\Users\lones\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\music\rpgmusic.mp3"

class VoiceChannelIntro(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Channel Intro cog successfully loaded.')

    @commands.Cog.event
    async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):
    #replace this with the path to your audio file
        path = r"path\to\music.mp3"

        vc_before = before.channel
        vc_after = after.channel
    
        if vc_before == vc_after:
            return
    
        elif vc_before is None:
            channel = member.voice.channel
            vc = await channel.connect()
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
            with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:
                #Start Playing
                sleep(f.duration)
            await vc.disconnect()

        elif vc_after is None:
            return
    
        else:
            channel = member.voice.channel
            vc = await channel.connect()
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
            with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:
                #Start Playing
                sleep(f.duration)
            await vc.disconnect()
        

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(VoiceChannelIntro(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of your mistakes:

1. Use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()`
2. You forgot to pass `self` as the first argument

Below is the revised code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

rpgmusicpath = r"C:\Users\lones\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\music\rpgmusic.mp3"

class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Music cog successfully loaded.')

    @commands.Cog.event
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
    #replace this with the path to your audio file
        path = r"C:\Users\lones\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\test-chamber-4-intro.mp3"

        vc_before = before.channel
        vc_after = after.channel
    
        if not vc_before and vc_after.id == YOUR VOICE CHANNEL ID:
            vc = await vc_after.connect()
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
            with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:
                #Start Playing
                sleep(f.duration)
            await vc.disconnect()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Comment: Hey, so I went to test it out, but I get an error. When I run the code, it says:
" AttributeError: type object 'Cog' has no attribute 'event' ". Any idea what might be causing this? I looked through the docs in Discord.py, but it didn't even mention anything about Cog.event.